# How to write simple fair semaphore?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I found simple realization of semaphore(my CustomSemaphore) and as I understand this is 'not fair' one because into secure block can enter only first thread all time(I am not sure).
How can I write fair semaphore(analog of concurrency `new Semaphore(1, true);`)

```
   public class SimpleSemaphoreSample2 {
    CustomSemaphore cSem = new CustomSemaphore(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleSemaphoreSample2 main = new SimpleSemaphoreSample2();
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, true);
        Thread thrdA = new Thread(main.new SyncOutput(sem, "Thread1"), "Thread1");
        Thread thrdB = new Thread(main.new SyncOutput(sem, "Thread2"), "Thread2");

        thrdA.start();
        thrdB.start();

        try {
            thrdB.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }

    class SyncOutput implements Runnable {
        private Semaphore sem;
        private String msg;

        public SyncOutput(Semaphore s, String m) {
            sem = s;
            msg = m;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
//                  sem.acquire();
                    cSem.acquire();
                    System.out.println("Before");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("After");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
//              sem.release();
                cSem.release();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomSemaphore {
        private int counter;

        public CustomSemaphore() {
            this(0);
        }

        public CustomSemaphore(int i) {
            if (i < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(i + " < 0");
            counter = i;
        }

        public synchronized void release() {
            if (counter == 0) {
                this.notify();
            }
            counter++;
        }

        public synchronized void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
            while (counter == 0) {
                this.wait();
            }
            counter--;
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Is this an assignment for a course? If it is, add a homework tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your semaphore is not fair because it is possible that a thread wait forever. Think about a mutex (binary semaphore) used to write a value by 3 threads. T1 acquire, T2 wait and T3 wait. Now during release, you notify and one between T2 and T3 take the semaphore (let say T2). Now T1 come back and wait. When T2 notify, T1 takes it. It can happen as many times as possible, and T3 will never have the semaphore.

One change can be to use a simple FIFO inside the semaphore. When an thread has to wait, you add his id in the Queue. Now when you notify, you notify to all the threads. The only thread which progress is the one which is at the head of the queue.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://books.google.com/books?ei=4YV0T-LLOcTi0QGFhqX_Ag&id=EK43StEVfJIC&dq=intrinsic%20locking%20fairness%20java&q=intrinsic%20locking%20offers%20no%20deterministic%20fairness#v=snippet&q=intrinsic%20locking%20offers%20no%20deterministic%20fairness&f=false)  it states that

> intrinsic locking offers no deterministic fairness guarantees

Intrinsic locking here is using `synchronized`.  So there is no way you can make this Semaphore example fair without replacing `synchronized` with `Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);`

Where the `true` as constructor argument tells the ReentrantLock to be *fair*

Edit based on a comment by @trutheality

If you really want it to be correct without using the ReentrantLock, you can implement the Semaphore inheriting the synchronization primitives from the [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html). This would prove to be quite complicated and if you can correctly write it with ReentrantLock I would suggest that.  Note: ReentrantLock delegates its synchronization to the AQS.

Comment: On the contrary, there are lots of ways to make things fair without using `ReentrantLock`: you could use a queue for example.

Comment: @UmNyobe I understand that, but there needs to be some form of synchronization, and if he tries to use `synchronized` at all it will fail to satisfy the fairness requirement.

Comment: @trutheality The thread-safe queue's, for example ArrayBlockingQueue, use a ReentrantLock to control fairness.  ABQ by default is not fair and is only fair when `true` is passed as a constructor arg.

Comment: @JohnVint And `ReentrantLock` itself is implemented using the queue inside `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`. It's a lot of work because you basically need to implement your own special queue, but it's doable without `ReentrantLock`.

Comment: @trutheality That's a good point, I thought you were naively referring to a standard Queue offered by Java.

Comment: @trutheality Updated my answer with respect to your comment, thanks!

Comment: Wrapping a type derived from `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` is the way to go here. `AQS`'s protected interface fits most closely with implementing a semaphore, as that's the most general concurrency control primitive.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of a reentrant semaphore, but is designed only for 2 pretenders. If you want to extend the code for more than 2 you must implement a simple list and make a few changes, including the test for `wait()` in the `aquire()` method.

```
package nmscd.utils;

/**
 * A simple, non-reentrant, one permit, FAIR semaphore
 * @author cosmo
 */
public class SimpleSemaphore {

    private boolean aquired = false;
    private Thread currThread;
    private Thread releasedThread;
    private int pretendersCount = 0;

    public synchronized void aquire() throws InterruptedException {
        while ((Thread.currentThread() != currThread && aquired) || (pretendersCount > 0 && Thread.currentThread() == releasedThread)) {
            pretendersCount++;
            try {
                wait();
            } finally {
                pretendersCount--;
            }
        }
        aquired = true;
        currThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }

    public synchronized void release() {
        if (Thread.currentThread() == currThread) {
            aquired = false;
            currThread = null;
            releasedThread = Thread.currentThread();
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

The key in this class is to test in the aquire method to see if the thread aquiring is the thread you want, all other threads must wait. So if you have enough info to determine that thread you can select which thread returns from `aquire()`